# how to filter a txt file with specific strings

Tags: python, string, filter

I have a file (file1.txt) where the first column contains strings, I want to filter in another file (file2.txt) the lines whose strings correspond exactly to the list 'indref' (see code). The problem is that the resulting file (see the short example) is also appending those strings that 'start' with the values that I want to append. I would just like to append the specific strings (those in 'indref'). Thank you.

```
import numpy as np

indref = ['p1', 'p3']

with open('file1.txt') as oldfile, open('file2.txt', 'w') as newfile:

    for line in oldfile:
        if any(x in line for x in indref):
            newfile.write(line)
```

Example of file1.txt

```
p1        4.252613E+01  
p2        4.245285E+01  
p3        4.272667E+01 
p4        4.255809E+01  
p5        4.284104E+01  
p6        4.292802E+01  
p7        4.295814E+01  
p8        4.286242E+01  
p9        4.286862E+01  
p10       4.258108E+01
```

file2.txt:

```
p1        4.252613E+01  
p3        4.272667E+01 
p10       4.258108E+01
```

Comment: Why is `p10` included? It doesn't seem to be in your `indref` list

Comment: Add a space or tab '\t' (depending on what you have in the file) after 'p1' or use regular expressions

Comment: @chrisz That is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a good answer for using `split` but it could be thinned down to

```
indref = ['p1', 'p3']

with open('file1.txt') as oldfile, open('file2.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    newfile.writelines(line for line in oldfile if line.split()[0] in indref)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` on each line, then check if the first element is in `indref`:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
  indref = {'p1', 'p3'}
  data = [i for i in f.read().splitlines() if i.split()[0] in indref]

  with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(data))
```

Output:

```
p1        4.252613E+01  
p3        4.272667E+01
```

I changed `indref` to a set, since lookups in sets are O(1) average time, and if it was a very large list lookups could be expensive.

Comment: This works but its odd to change from the original line by line implementation to one that reads the entire file and splits.